# Select rows based on values from 1 column being the same?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, cte, window-functions

An example of my database table

```
film id | scene id | value id
-----------------------------
   0    |     0    |     7
   0    |     1    |     1
   0    |     1    |     0
   1    |     2    |     8
   1    |     2    |     3
   1    |     3    |     1
   2    |     4    |     3
   2    |     4    |     7
   2    |     5    |     2
```

I want to select rows where the value id is equal to 8 or 3 only if they are both in a row with the same scene id.

My desired result would be:

```
film id | scene id | value id
-----------------------------
   1    |     2    |     8
   1    |     2    |     3
```

I tried grouping by count of scene id but it would output this:

```
film id | scene id | value id
-----------------------------
   1    |     2    |     8
   1    |     2    |     3
   2    |     4    |     3
```

where the last row was included because there were multiple values of scene id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for selecting values based on a specific column being the same you could have a look at [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Distributes the rows in an ordered partition into a specified number
>   of groups.  The groups are numbered, starting at one.  For each row,
>   NTILE returns the number of the group to which the row belongs.

there are actually many options, including [common_table_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

on your example:

```
--==================================================================================
use tempdb
if object_id('tempdb..radhe','U') is not null
   drop table radhe

create table  radhe(
 [Film Id] int not null
,[Scene Id] int not null
,[Value Id]int not null
)


insert into radhe ([Film Id],[Scene Id],[Value Id])
select 
   0    ,     0    ,     7
union all select 
   0    ,     1    ,     1
union all select 
   0    ,     1    ,     0
union all select 
   1    ,     2    ,     8
union all select 
   1    ,     2    ,     3
union all select 
   1    ,     3    ,     1
union all select 
   2    ,     4    ,     3
union all select 
   2    ,     4    ,     7
union all select 
   2    ,     5    ,     2



--I want to select rows 
--where the value id is equal to 8 or 3 
--only if they are both in a row with the same scene id.


--using a cte
;with t8 as (

        SELECT r.[Film Id], r.[Scene Id], r.[Value Id]
        FROM radhe r
        WHERE r.[Value Id]IN (8) 
) ,
t3 as (


        SELECT r.[Film Id], r.[Scene Id], r.[Value Id]
        FROM radhe r
        WHERE r.[Value Id]IN (3) 
)

select t8.* 
from t8
inner join t3
        on t8.[Scene Id] = t3.[Scene Id]
union all
select t3.* 
from t8
inner join t3
        on t8.[Scene Id] = t3.[Scene Id]

--====================================================================

--using NTILE
select r.[Film Id], r.[Scene Id], r.[Value Id]
from
(
SELECT 
    NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY [Scene Id]) [NTILE],
    *
FROM Radhe
WHERE [Value Id]IN (3,8) 
) r
where r.NTILE = 1
```

[image]

the results are the same but what about the performance?

[image]

check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/197274/22336) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77642/22336) out.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is clear for current sample data.
But there can be so many scenario.

Another approach,  same sample data

```
use tempdb
if object_id('tempdb..radhe','U') is not null
   drop table radhe

create table  radhe(
 [Film Id] int not null
,[Scene Id] int not null
,[Value Id]int not null
)


insert into radhe ([Film Id],[Scene Id],[Value Id])
select 
   0    ,     0    ,     7
union all select 
   0    ,     1    ,     1
union all select 
   0    ,     1    ,     0
union all select 
   1    ,     2    ,     8
union all select 
   1    ,     2    ,     3
union all select 
   1    ,     3    ,     1
union all select 
   2    ,     4    ,     3
union all select 
   2    ,     4    ,     7
union all select 
   2    ,     5    ,     2
```

Create another temp table or table variable.In this table `pre insert the desire condition`.

```
declare @t table([Scene Id] int not null,[Value Id]int not null)
insert into @t values(2,8),(2,3)
```

Final query

```
select r.*
   from radhe r inner join @t t on 
    r.[Scene Id] = t.[Scene Id] and r.[Value Id] = t.[Value Id]
```

So like I told you, if I know the exact requirement and diffrent scenario.Then I will pre populate my table accordingly.

Depending upon exact requirement,it has its limitation.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
create table FILM
(
  film_id  NUMBER,
  scene_id NUMBER,
  value_id NUMBER
)

insert into FILM ([film_id],[scene_id],[value_id])
select 
   0    ,     0    ,     7
union all select 
   0    ,     1    ,     1
union all select 
   0    ,     1    ,     0
union all select 
   1    ,     2    ,     8
union all select 
   1    ,     2    ,     3
union all select 
   1    ,     3    ,     1
union all select 
   2    ,     4    ,     3
union all select 
   2    ,     4    ,     7
union all select 
   2    ,     5    ,     2
union all select
   3    ,     2    ,     3
union all select
   3    ,     2    ,     8
union all select
   3    ,     5    ,     9
```

Final Query:

```
select t.*
  from FILM t
 where t.value_id in (8, 3)
   and exists (select t2.film_id, t2.scene_id, t2.value_id
          from film t2
         where t.scene_id = t2.scene_id
           and t2.value_id = 8)
```

Output :

```
film id | scene id | value id
-----------------------------
   1    |     2    |     3
   1    |     2    |     8
   3    |     2    |     8   
   3    |     2    |     3
```